# Search for folder in Google Drive python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, drive

Problem is I want to upload files to google drive what I have already sorted, but the problem is I need to get the `folder_id` of the folder named `Location` in gdrive. Normally I would use the provided library from google, but I can't authenticate with my access_token so I need to get this done by REST api.

I already tried searching after it but always get `Invalid Value`, if I do

```
files = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?access_token=" + access_token + "&q=name%20%3D%20%27Location%27")
```

Only to clarify if I remove the query then it functions.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `"Location"` a valid folder in your Drive?

Comment: Could you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? that way we can have a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: yes the folder "Location" exists, sorry but I can't share my access_token

Comment: You could still share your code and simply remove sensitive information out of it, that will at least show what your code is doing.

Comment: I'm sorry if you expected more but this part of my code, that gives me the folder id for a folder name that already exists, is everything

Comment: You cloud also parse the whole json output, but I was never successfull with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your showing script, even when the files and folders of the name of `Location` are not existing, the value is returned like `"files": []` instead of `Invalid Value`. And, for example, when an access token is invalid, the error like `"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg"` and `"reason": "authError"` occurs. And, when the value of `q` is invalid, the error of `Invalid Value` for `"location": "q"` occurs.

When I saw your search query, it is `name = 'Location'`. I think that this is correct. Although, I cannot replicate your situation, in order to retrieve the folder ID of `Location` folder, can you test the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote

access_token = "###" # Please set your access token.

q = "name='Location' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"
files = requests.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?access_token="
    + access_token
    + "&q="
    + quote(q)
)
print(files.text)
```

#### Sample script 2:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote

access_token = "###" # Please set your access token.

q = "name='Location' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"
files = requests.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?&q=" + quote(q),
    headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token},
)
print(files.text)
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, the following value is returned.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "###",
   "name": "Location",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
  }
 ]
}
```

From this result, you can retrieve the folder ID.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)